# Running programmatically created Rscript call at command line

Tags: r, bash, rscript

I have the following script:

*rstest*

```
text=$1

cmd="Rscript -e \"a='$1'; print(a)\""
echo $cmd
$cmd
```

This is the output I get when I run it:

```
balter@spectre3:~$ bash rstest hello
Rscript -e "a='hello'; print(a)"
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
```

However, if I run the echoed command directly, it runs fine:

```
balter@spectre3:~$ Rscript -e "a='hello'; print(a)"

[1] "hello"
```

I would like to understand why this is. I've tried various combinations of quoting the bash variables and adding `eval`. But that doesn't seem to be the issue.

**EDIT**

I tried the answer given below, but get a different result!

```
balter@spectre3:~$ cat rstest
text=$1

cmd="Rscript -e \"a=$1; print(a)\""
echo $cmd
eval $cmd

balter@spectre3:~$ bash rstest
Rscript -e "a=; print(a)"
Error in cat("pointing to conda env:", env_name, "and lib location", lib,  :
  argument "env_name" is missing, with no default
Calls: startCondaEnv -> cat
Execution halted
```

Comment: I think you want `eval $cmd` rather than just `$cmd`

Comment: That did not change the behavior :(

Answer (score 1):

Below script worked for me.

```
text=$1

cmd="Rscript -e \"a='$1'; print(a)\""
echo $cmd
eval $cmd
```

Removing `eval` gave the same error you posted.

```
Rscript -e "a='Hello'; print(a)"
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I added to the original post trying to run what you gave. I get the same error! I'm running this in Ubuntu 18.10. You?

Comment: Mint 19.1 and R 3.6.0; i think after you used `eval` you changed `cmd` and forget to add the apostrophe around `$1`.